# Nginx + Cloudfront, Duplicate access-control-allow-origin

Tags: nginx, header, amazon-cloudfront

I am scratching my head with this. I have a wordpress site on Digital Ocean running Nginx. I also have a cloudfront distribution with default settings and SSL certificate issued by amazon.

For testing purposes I have ensured that I have removed from Nginx:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

When I check in Chrome Network tab my css and js files still are shown with duplicate headers like this:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

These duplicate headers are shown irrespective of whether I add the Access-Control header in Nginx. Furthermore this only happens when cloudfront is added to my caching plugin.